# VMWare clients: replace an existing server with a clone

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-esx, cloning

Consider two Win2k3 servers: SRV01 and SRV02. These two servers perform the same function in the domain, and have the same software installed.

SRV01 runs without issue.
SRV02 has problems problems that we've troubleshot down to the OS. We've reinstalled the faulty software to try to correct the issue.

So now we want to clone SRV01 (which works great) and replace SRV02 with this clone. This will help to rule out something funky with the OS.

Both SRV01 and SRV02 are VMs on VMWare's Virtual Center 3.5.x platform.

I'm looking for some feedback on whether this will plan of action would break something:

1. Detach SRV02 from the domain
2. Turn SRV02 off
3. Clone SRV01, and make it the *new* SRV02
4. Turn *new* SRV02 on, with the NIC disabled
5. Re-IP *new* SRV02 to be the same IP as the old one
6. Join the *new* SRV02 to the domain

Will this work? Am I going to break something with the SIDs that will break this *new* SRV02? Again, the goal is to replace the faulting SRV02 with a clone of SRV01, and have the domain, and all UNC/DFS paths that point to SRV02 work without issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have most of the steps and what you proposed would probably work. I recommend that you follow [these](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/169641) steps.

In my opinion, this is one of the best benefits from Virtualization.